# How to manage serializers in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I use the following serializer in my ViewSet to create some `Instance`:

```py
class InstanceCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Instance
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name", "description", "company",
            "err_msg", "is_valid",
        ]
```

---

The fields `author`, `company`, `is_valid` and `err_msg` **must be set** by the service, **not  by the user**. But if i use `read_only_fields`, as in the code below, then these fields cannot be changed by the service either.

```py
class InstanceCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Instance
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name", "description",
            "author", "company",
            "err_msg", "is_valid",
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            "author", "company",
            "err_msg", "is_valid", 
        ]
```

---

### **How can I manage serializers or prevent the user from submitting values for these fields?**

---

##### Additionally, these fields are available for input in the DRF Browsable API and Swagger, which is something I also want to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [HiddenField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield) to not accept any data from user but populate it in `validated_data`.

For example, you want the current user to be set as the `author` for your model. You can use HiddenField like this.

```py
class InstanceCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Instance
        fields = [
            ...
            "author",
        ]
```

As mentioned by others, you can also use `validate` method to validate/set your values.

```py
class InstanceCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def validate(self, attrs: dict) -> dict:
        attrs["company"] = attrs["author"].company
        return attrs
```

If you want to set values only while creating/updating, use the respective `create` or `update` methods.

```py
class InstanceCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data: dict):
        validated_data["company"] = validated_data["author"].company
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data: dict):
        validated_data["company"] = validated_data["author"].company
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Comment: Also seems like a good solution. Thanks for spending your time!